# Is it possible to programmatically delay a monitor's vertical retrace?

Tags: nvidia, hdmi, vsync

Given FreeSync and GSync it is now possible that graphics card and monitor work together to support variable frame rates and control when a monitor refreshes.

My question is if with a fixed framerate monitor there is any way to do something similar in a very limited way. I would like to cause a slight delay of the vertical retrace of a monitor (via HDMI / DVI) to come in sync with an external image source.

Is this possible based on TMDS based video connections? Is this something any graphics cards exposes?

Comment: It sounds like you're after genlock ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genlock ) - AFAIK this can only be performed in hardware, not software.

Comment: It seems like WGL_I3D_genlock might provide a way. Is it widely supported?